# Sample rhomobile apps

Tags: rhomobile, sample

There are some features which I wanted to see the behaviour for in Rhomobile applications and compare them to the native apps. In particular,

> **Location based results**: can we control how it behaves when no location services are available and perform different actions.

Any pointers to sample **apps that have been deployed to the app store or Google play**? I have been searching through the rhomobile.com ([which redirects](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Software+and+Applications/RhoMobile+Suite)) but couldn't find any samples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any example apps, but does [this example app sampling native system functions](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes-system-api-samples) help?